# Texmaker on Ubuntu, autocomplete doesn't work properly

Tags: texmaker, auto-completion

When I type `\ref{...`， there is a list of available items. But when I confirm an item by clicking <kbd>Enter</kbd>, instead of filling that item, Texmaker create a new subsection at the end of document. However, the autocompletion of `\begin{...}` works well. How can I fix this problem?